# pandas: create a column from an inverse mapping of a dictionay

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with company names and a dictionary that maps all variations of names to one official name.

I want to create a new column with the official name based on that dictionary. Is there a more concise way than iterating through the key-values in the dict?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['company a', 'company a inc', 'a electronics', 'company a ltd', 'the company a', 'b enterprises', 'company b']})

name_dict = {'company a' : ['company a', 'company a inc', 'a electronics', 'company a ltd', 'the company a'],
'company b' : ['b enterprises', 'company b']}

def get_company_name(name):
    for k, v in name_dict.items():
        if name in v:
            return k

df['official_name'] = df.name.apply(get_company_name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create the forward dictionary and replace:

```
forward_names = {v:k  for k, val in name_dict.items() for v in val }
df['official_name'] = df['name'].replace(forward_names)
```

Comment: Although `.replace()` is quite slow compared to `.map()`, it does a better job of keeping the original value if a replacement isn't found. Even if you pass `na_action='ignore'` to `.map()`.

Comment: @robroc Thanks, I've always been under the impression that `replace` is faster that `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just browse the `name_dict` directory to build the rows of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[v,k] for k in name_dict for v in name_dict[k]],
                  columns = ['name', 'official_name'])
```

Comment: This assumes the real data is in the same order and frequency as the dict in the fake example data I provided. Do you mean that I should make a dataframe of name variations and use that as the mapping reference?

Answer (score 0):

solution1:

```
def get_company_name(name):
    return [k for k, v in name_dict.items() if name in v][0]

df['official_name'] = df.name.apply(get_company_name)
print (df)
```

solution2:

```
df['official_name'] = df.name.apply(lambda name: list(k for k, v in name_dict.items() if name in v)[0])
print (df)
```

output:

```
            name official_name
0      company a     company a
1  company a inc     company a
2  a electronics     company a
3  company a ltd     company a
4  the company a     company a
5  b enterprises     company b
6      company b     company b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put name_dict into a dataframe and then melt and then merge it:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(name_dict, orient='index')
df2 = df2.transpose()
df2 = df2.melt()
df3 = df.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='name', right_on='value', sort=False)
```